# not showing alertdialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

```
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener clickListener= new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which)
                {
                    case BUTTON_POSITIVE :
                        udb.signout();
                        break;

                    case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setTitle("Notification");
        builder.setMessage("You are already logged in.\nDo you want to signout and login with different account?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",clickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",clickListener);
        builder.show();
```

this my code for showing pop up dialog box.. but I'm getting problem on
"builder.show()" line. And I can't understand what i did wrong. Please. I'll appreciate any help

Comment: Consider adding the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as I tested personally on my device,

```
builder.show();
```

should has the same effect as

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

no matter **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog** or **android.app.AlertDialog** is used.

In my case, I found what is causing the problem is the way **AlertDialog.Builder** is initialized.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

From [Dialog documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), you need to pass in an **Activity** to this constructor, which the followings will work:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

or,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(<YourActivity>.this);
```

Comment: it worked properly, when i updated AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(<MyActivity>.this);

Answer (score 1):

You have to `create` dialog of your `AlertDialog.Builder` and then show it...remove `builder.show();`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setTitle("Notification");
builder.setMessage("You are already logged in.\nDo you want to signout and login with different account?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",clickListener);
builder.setNegativeButton("No",clickListener);   


AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First  call builder.create() . You cannot  display  the builder  itself.

Comment: isnt it `.create()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create AlertDialog object using the AlertDialog.Builder object and show dialog. For e.g.,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

/*All your dialog code*/

//Create AlertDialog object
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create ();
//show the AlertDialog using show() method
alertDialog.show();
```